# When I click on Done button in the image will be change in previous UIviewController?

Tags: iphone, uiimage

Am changing the profile picture first screen when I click on image it will going into the next screen and in this it asking choose from gallery or take a picture. Suppose I choose from gallery, it comes in to the second screen and the image is appearing. My question is when I click on done button in second screen  the image will change in first screen, that is profile picture.How it will change in first screen,Please reply me.

Comment: Create delegate for image selection in second view controller, assign it as first view controller. When image is selected by user, pass that image in the delegate callback.

Comment: How to create delegate for Image?

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate in `SecondViewController` class. Assign and implement this delegate in `FirstViewController` class.

When user selects the image from gallery, or clicks a photo, call the delegate method to pass the selected image to `FirstViewController` class.

Sample code to implement this is as below

## SecondViewController.h

```
// Declare delegate
@protocol ImageSelectionDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) imageSelected:(UIImage*)image;
@end

@interface SecondViewController : UIViewController
// Delegate property
@property (nonatomic,assign) id<ImageSelectionDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

## SecondViewController.m

```
@implementation SecondViewController

// In case you are using image picker, this delegate is called once image selection is complete.
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
                        didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    //Use either according to your setting, whether you allow image editing or not.
    UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    //For edited image
    //UIImage *myImage = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageSelected:)]) {
        [self.delegate imageSelected:myImage];
    }
}

//OR

// Done button click
- (IBAction)doneButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    // You can store the image selected by user in a UIImage pointer.
    // Here I have UIImage *selectedImage as an ivar.

    // Call the delegate and pass the selected image.
    if([_delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(imageSelected:)]) {
        [self.delegate imageSelected:selectedImage];
    }

    // Pop the view controller here
}

@end
```

## FirstViewController.h

```
#import "SecondViewController.h"

@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController <ImageSelectionDelegate>

@end
```

## FirstViewController.m

```
@implementation FirstViewController
- (void) onImageClick {
    SecondViewController *controller = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
    // Assign delegate
    controller.delegate = self;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
}

// Implement delegate method
- (void) imageSelected:(UIImage *)image {
    // Use image
}
@end
```

Comment: Why your pushing secondviewcontroller.In secondviewcontroller the done button is there. So We can pop in secondviewcontroller is it right or not?

Comment: If you are presenting the second view controller modally then that's okay! No need to push on navigation stack.

Comment: No When I click on done button in secondviewcontroler it wiil be change in firstrviewcontroler so can use I popviewcontroller or not?

Comment: This code will pass the image to firstViewcontroller as soon as the user selects the image. It does not have dependency on done button click. If you want it that way then call the delegate on done button click instead. After calling delegate method, you can pop the view controller.

Comment: Check edited answer, I have added code to call delegate in done button click.